# MVC 1.0 Compatibility with VS 2010

Tags: model-view-controller

We are planning to upgrade our technology to VS 2010. But I wonder if the MVC 2.0 is  working properly since it has many issues raised from software developer who used it please see here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742.I want to use MVC 1.0 in VS 2010 is it compatible?

Comment: MVC2 works fine. Don't fear it.

Comment: Hi Robaticus, did you tried it?Is there no issues encountered in using MVC 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as Robaticus said, MVC2 works well and you shouldn't be afraid to use it... but if you really want to stick with MVC 1.0, take the relevant MVC DLLs and copy them into a known lib folder, and then directly link your project to those.  By doing this, you will be directly linking to the old MVC libraries which will still work just fine.  Just don't link to any of the MVC 2.0 libraries that will undoubtedly be sitting in the Global Assembly Cache.

Answer (score 0):

MVC 2 works great; I'm using it right now.  There are some very slight changes to the signature of some framework components, but overall works great.  Would recommend 2 because they have a lot of new features to take advantage of and make your life easier.

If you had to, MVC 1 and MVC 2 they give you the source code, which you can include and use in your project, so you are always covered there.

MVC 1 and MVC 2 are compiled in .NET 3.5 SP 1 version, so you may be able to use the MVC 1 DLL directly...

HTH.